# How to run a job every 6 hours starting at 3:00 using runwhen

Tags: daemontools

I try to make [runwhen](http://code.dogmap.org/runwhen/) perform a job every 6 hours, starting at 3:00 in the morning.

(How) Can this be done?

Comment: any reason not to just use cron?

Comment: there are some reasons (on this page in german: http://uberspace.de/dokuwiki/system:runwhen), they are: no collisions, execute time in settings, integrated logging, information when next execution takes place, do it now feature, temporary break. however finally I decided for cron :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found a solution - if somebody else is interested...

```
#!/bin/sh -e

RUNWHEN=",H/6"

# The constraint string consists of a sequence of unit constraints. Each unit
# constraint consists of a comma, one of the following letters indicating which
# unit is constrained:
#
#     * y: year.
#     * m: month (in the range 1-12).
#     * d: day of the month (in the range 1-28, 1-29, 1-30, or 1-31, as
#          appropriate for the month in question).
#     * w: day of the week (in the range 0-6, with 0 representing Sunday).
#     * H: hour of the day (in the range 0-23).
#     * M: minute of the hour (in the range 0-59).
#     * S: second of the minute (in the range 0-59). 
#
# and finally one of the following:
#
#     * =n: matches times when the given unit is exactly n.
#     * -n: matches times when the given unit is exactly m, where m+n is one
#           more than the largest value of the unit. (For example, n+m=24 for H,
#           so ,H-1 is equivalent to ,H=23.
#     * /n: matches times when the given unit is divisible by n. 

exec 2>&1 \
rw-add n d1S now1s \
rw-match \$now1s $RUNWHEN wake \
## here comes the interesting part
rw-add \$wake d3H wake \
sh -c '
  echo "@$wake" | tai64nlocal | sed "s/^/next run time: /"
  exec "$@"' arg0 \
rw-sleep \$wake \
thescript
```